# How to set integer range in Scanner?

Tags: java

I am learning java and I want to create a command-line application that calculates exam percentages based on marks obtained. But the problem is I don't have the idea to set the range of marks obtained while the marks range is between 0 to 100.

Below is the code, I have tried: -

```
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
public class CbseCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of Physics");
        float physics = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of Chemistry");
        float chemistry = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of Math");
        float math = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of English");
        float english = sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of Computer Science");
        float computer = sc.nextFloat();
        float total = 500;
        float obtained = (physics + chemistry + math + english + computer);
        float percentage = (obtained/total)*100;
        System.out.println("The percentage obtained is: "+percentage);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried based on your research and reading the javadoc for the package?

Comment: Strange that no one has pointed this out yet, always post code as text and never as an image.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i am new to StackOverflow and Coding. I will learn how to do it soon. Well thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to try to get `Scanner` to do that<sup>1</sup>.

Instead, you should use `Scanner` to read an `int` and then test the result that it gives you to check that it is in the correct range.  Something like this:

```
int number;
if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
    number = myScanner.nextInt();
    if (number < 0 || number > 100) {
        // handle case where the number is out of range
    }
} else {
    // handle case where the input is not an integer
}
```

I will leave it to you to figure out how to map the above onto your application's requirements.

---

<sup>1 - The standard `Scanner` class doesn't provide a method that reads a number in a given range (and rejects numbers outside of that range).  You could *conceivably* extend the `Scanner` class with this functionality, but it would be difficult.  There are simpler solutions.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write a function to get a valid input as below :-

```
public int getValidInput(Scanner in, int range) {
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        if (in.hasNextInt()) {
            int val = in.nextInt();
            if (val >= 0 && val < range) { // <-- from "0" to "range".
                return val;
            }
        } else {
            in.next();
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This function is ensuring that the input is given as an integer only and it lies in the range `o` to `range`. You can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this method:

```
static int getMark(String course){
    int mark = 0;
    boolean valid = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter marks obtained of " + course + ": ");

    while(valid){
      mark = sc.nextInt();
      if(mark < 0 || mark > 100){
        System.out.println("Mark must be between 0-100");
      } else {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
    sc.close();
    return mark;
}
```

This way you can get two birds with one stone, leaving the resulting code as this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int physics = getMark("Physics");
  int chemistry = getMark("Chemistry");
  int math = getMark("Math");
  int english = getMark("English");
  int computer = getMark("Computer Science");

  float total = 500;
  float obtained = (physics + chemistry + math + english + computer);
  float percentage = (obtained / total) * 100;

  System.out.println("The percentage obtained is: " + percentage);
}
```

Comment: You have initialized as `boolean valid = false`, so the while loop won't be executed even once. Also, the `Scanner` object is local to `main`, you need to pass that as well to the `getMark` method

Comment: The method was more meant to convey a way of doing things, rather than to be an example of perfect code. Initially I didn't even include that code in my answer.